# Issue to add space on top of coordinate layout and animation is not that smoothly

Tags: android, scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

We have an toolbar in our app and I have to add coordinate layout below to that.
In that we have an image,and in that below we have an tabs and at last on the below we have an View-pager with list view.

Basically I trying to do this below:-

1. When we scroll up the image needs to scroll up and the tabs are stick below to the toolbar and list item are shown to the below tabs.

But while trying I am facing an following issue:-

1. An Extra space added on top of the coordinator layout.
2. An animation is not smooth while scrolling up

   ```
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
       android:id="@+id/appBarLayout_tour_series"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/white"

      >

       <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
           android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_player_stats"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
           app:contentScrim="@android:color/white"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
         >

           <au.com.cricket.util.DynamicNetworkImageView
               android:id="@+id/series_header_bg"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:adjustViewBounds="true"
               android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               />

           <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/series_header"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
               >

               <au.com.cricket.util.FadeInNetworkImageView
                   android:id="@+id/img_team_logo"
                   android:layout_width="72dp"
                   android:layout_height="72dp"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                   tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>


               <com.outware.common.ui.widget.OMTextView
                   android:id="@+id/txt_series_name"
                   style="@style/Home.Text.MatchDetail.TeamName"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/img_team_logo"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                   android:paddingLeft="80dp"
                   android:paddingRight="80dp"
                   android:paddingTop="10dp"
                   android:text="KFC BBL|05"
                   android:textColor="@color/color_charcoal_black"
                   android:textSize="18sp"
                   custom:customFont="TabletGothicNarrow-Bold.otf"
                   tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
                   />

               <com.outware.common.ui.widget.OMTextView
                   android:id="@+id/txt_match_status"
                   style="@style/Home.Text.MatchDetail.TeamName"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@id/txt_series_name"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:bufferType="spannable"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                   android:text="date range"
                   android:textColor="@color/text_home_grey"
                   android:textSize="11sp"
                   custom:customFont="TabletGothic.otf"
                   tools:ignore="HardcodedText"

                   />

               <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/notify_icon"
                   android:layout_width="40dp"
                   android:layout_height="40dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/txt_match_status"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_fixtures_notify_series"
                   android:visibility="gone"
                   tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                   />
           </RelativeLayout>


       </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:fillViewport="true"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       >


       <include layout="@layout/fragment_tab_series_layout"/>


   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
   ```

**Now I am able to fix the first issue about the space on top but not able to fix the smooth animation as its still lagging when we scroll up.**

**And also one more issue I observed that the collapsable layout is not collapse fully as some lower part of header layout I seen once we scroll up.
I updated the above code.** Please check.

Screehshot:-

[image]

Comment: animation is not smooth because of image you have populated in coordinator layout try to use a low quality image or rescale your image beofre using it

Comment: @AdeelTurk : Now I am able to fix the first issue as the space in the top bar gets removed but I am facing an another issue is the collapsible layout is not collapsible fully. As in the bottom the some part of header lower part is visible when we scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample [project](https://github.com/adeelturk/Collapsing-Tool-viewpager-and-tabs) with almost same ui it might help you and i would suggest to use a bit low quality image or rescale your bitmap before using it in coordianatorlayout child